# If I have my WIFI on at the same time as VPN, what IP address does a site / app pick up on?

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn

I'm trying to access an app on my phone where I got blocked or at least shadow blocked, and they wouldn't tell me why.
I've tried using VPN and was able to get in and see some features at first and then I got blocked again.
Is this due to having my home wifi on as well as the vpn?
Does the order of turning which one on first affect what IP address does the site pick up on?
Should I ask my ISP to change my IP in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There are by far better means - like fingerprinting your hardware - to identify you(r phone) than tracking IP addresses. So obfuscating or changing your IP address will probably not be sufficient to use the app again.